# Highcharts angular wrapper labels.items don't refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm using angular6 and the office highcharts angular wrapper (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) in version 2.4.0.

Everything is working good except the labels that can be placed manually on the chart.

I just don't manage to get them refreshed.
I have a graph that can be filtered through the back-end. When I get the new generated data I update the data in my chartOptions which are used in the html as  `[options]="chartOptions"` for the angular component.

The chartOptions are instanciated from my default class like this: `this.chartOptions = new GraphConfigSeqAtteptedVsAchived().chartOptions;`

The Class looks like this:
`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

export class GraphConfigSeqAtteptedVsAchived{
    public chartOptions: any;

```
constructor(){
    this.chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        height: 600,
        width: 620,
        events:{load: function(){
            this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);         
            }
        },
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    credits: {
        text: 'charname',
        href: ''
    },
    labels: {

    },
    exporting:{
        chartOptions:{
            title: {
                text:'not set',
                style:{
                    color: '#000000'
                },
                margin: 0
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: -10,
        max: 0,
        width: 535,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
            style: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        reversed: true,
        tickInterval: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: -10,
        max: 0, 
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
            style: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        reversed: true,
        tickInterval: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: ' as',
        margin: 0,
        style:{
            color: 'transparent'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 90,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 1,
        navigation: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            stickyTracking: false,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                radius: 3,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '',
                hideDelay: 500
            },
            symbol: "circle",
            events: {

                mouseOut: function() {
                    this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
                    this.chart.myTooltip.options.enabled = false;
                },
                mouseOver: function() {
                    if(this.halo) {
                        this.halo.attr({
                           'class': 'highcharts-tracker' 
                        }).toFront();   
                    }
                },
                click: function(event) {
                    this.chart.myTooltip.options.enabled = true;
                    this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(event.point, event);
                }                  
            }  
        },
        line:{
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    return false; 
                }
            }
        },
        series:{
            allowPointSelect: true
        }

    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: [[30, 30], [-30, -30]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },      
        showInLegend: false,    
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)",
        enableMouseTracking: false
    },{
        type: 'line',
        data: [[30, 29.5], [-29.5, -30]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },          
        showInLegend: false,
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
        color: "rgba(125, 162, 159, 0.35)",
        enableMouseTracking: false
    },{
        type: 'line',
        data: [[29.5, 30], [-30, -29.5]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        showInLegend: false,
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
        color: "rgba(125, 162, 159, 0.35)",
        enableMouseTracking: false
    },{
        type: 'line',
        data: [[29, 30], [-30, -29]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        showInLegend: false,
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',         
        color: "rgba(197, 144, 161, 0.35)",
        enableMouseTracking: false
    },{
        type: 'line',
        data: [[30, 29], [-29, -30]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        showInLegend: false,
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
        color: "rgba(197, 144, 161, 0.35)",
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }]
}
}
```

}`

The generated data is in the typescript dynamically added and all of that works just fine. Everything is refreshed after I set the updateFlag for `[(update)]="updateGraph"`. The axis titles are also fine.

The only thing that's not refreshed for me are the labels i dynamically added to the chart like this:
`let labelTotalNumberOfEyes = {
                    html : this.translate.instant('GRAPHS.TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EYES') + ': ' + (scatterSeries.data.length + scatterSeriesRetreatment.data.length),
                    style : {
                        left : '330px',
                        top : '368px',
                        fontSize : '14px',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    }
                }

                this.chartOptions.labels.items.push(labelTotalNumberOfEyes);`

Does someone have any idea what I'm might doing wrong? I don't see any further option than just setting this update flag and it works fine for everything but the labels.

Please let me know if you're missing any information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `chart.redraw()`?

Comment: Unfortunately the angular wrapper doesn't have that option. They implemented a update flag for it but that only seems to work for the series and axis. So the chart.redraw() is not an option in this setup.

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow in online code editor like codesandbox or stackblitz? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4.

Comment: Thank you for the well prepared template @WojciechChmiel. I adapted the template and just added one label and edited the text in the update char function. You can see that the label is not changed but the whole rest. That's exactly the problem that I have as well. Here's my changed version https://codesandbox.io/s/l22jr69wjq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is actually a Highcharts bug. I've reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10429.

As a workaround, you can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to add a custom label and store reference to it in your component. Next, when updating, call `attr()` method on the label (Highcharts.SVGElement) and set new options. Check demo and code posted below.

**Add a label on chart callback:**

```
  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;

      self.label = chart.renderer
        .text("test", 100, 100)
        .css({
          fill: "#555",
          fontSize: 16
        })
        .add()
        .toFront();
    };
  }
```

**call attr() on the label while updating:**

```
  update_chart() {
    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    chart.showLoading();
    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.hideLoading();

      self.chartOptions.series = [
        {
          data: [10, 25, 15],
          name: "updatedSerieName"
        }
      ];
      self.chartOptions.yAxis.title.text = "updatedData";

      self.label
        .attr({
          text: "test1",
          x: 150,
          y: 120
        })
        .css({
          fill: "red",
          fontSize: 20
        });

      self.updateFromInput = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/8zo0yvqqwj

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Thank you very much @WojciechChmiel. I'll give it a try this week then and let you know if it worked for my purpose.

Comment: your proposal worked fine but after all I switched to the new annotations of Highcharts as mentioned in your reported bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10429